# Complex Numbers Question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

[image]

I answered the first part of the question. But I'm having a trouble with the second part. I can only find the half-line at $2i$ and $\theta=\pi/6$.

Here's the solution guide:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically $|z-3|=|z-3i|$ denotes all the points equally distant from $3$ and $3i$. This is exactly the midline (perpendicular bisector) of the segment $[3,3i]$.

Find the perpendicular direction and midpoint and you are done.

If you want to solve this algebraically, note that

$$|z-3|=|z-3i| \Leftrightarrow |z-3|^2=|z-3i|^2$$
Now using $|w|^2=w\bar{w}$ you get

$$(z-3)(\bar{z}-3)=(z-3i)(\bar{z}-\bar{3i})$$
$$z\bar{z}-3(z+\bar{z}) +9= z\bar{z}-3i\bar{z}+3iz+9$$
$$-3z-3\bar{z}=3iz-3i\bar{z}$$

Write $z=x+iy$ and solve.

Comment: What does the first line mean in the solution guide I posted?

Comment: @user102148 One of the equations is a half-line from $2i$ the direction $\pi/6$, as you stated; the other is the line from 0 in the direction $\pi/4$ (because, as stated in the solution above, it is the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining 3 and $3i$.)  These 2 lines intersect at the point $P$.  The 3 points 0, $P$, and $2i$ form a triangle.  This is the triangle that the "solution" is referring to (by the way, what you posted doesn't look like a solution at all, but is instead a "grading rubric" that explains how partial credit should be assigned).